# SQL - Select name, no matter upper or lower case letters

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I try to select all names with "Schmidt". But some names are lower case and some upper case.

I try this :

```
Select * from Account
where name like '%chmidt%'
or name like '%CHMIDT%'
```

But when one letter inside the word is upper case(e.g. SchmidT), the statement didnt find this.
Know somebody a easy way to solve this problem ?

Comment: I switched the database tag to "oracle" (removing MySQL) because the behavior better fits Oracle than MySQL.

Comment: Yes, this does not apply to T-SQL either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using Oracle and not MySQL, because it is case senstive by default.  Just use the `upper()` or `lower()` functions:

```
Select *
from Account
where lower(name) like '%chmidt%';
```

I would add an `s` if you want names like "Schmidt":

```
Select a.*
from Account a
where lower(a.name) like '%schmidt%';
```

Note:  This will find `hammerschmidt` and similar names.  If you want an exact match, remove the wildcards or use `=`.

Comment: This is the most complete and correct answer and should be accepted as such.

Answer (score 0):

Do a lower case comparison:

```
Select * from Account
where lower(name) like '%chmidt%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for Schmidt, my preference (for readability) is to use neither LOWER nor UPPER, but INITCAP - and equality, not the LIKE operator. Like so:

```
select ...    where initcap(name) = 'Schmidt'
```